# How to add local group to "Remote Desktop Users" group in Windows 7 pro

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I created a local group (say `ToolUsers`). I want to add this group to "Remote Desktop Users" so that these user can login remotely via MSTSC.

When I try to add, this local group is not visible & hence it isn't getting added.

Is this possible at all in Windows 7 x64 Pro?

My goal is to allow uses belonging to `ToolUsers` to access this PC remotely but no admin privilages

Environemnt: Windows 7 x64 Prof

Comment: Where is it not visible? If you look at the Windows 7 machine, there's no ToolUsers group under Local Users & Groups > Groups?

Comment: It isn't visible when I try to add the group under "Remote Desktop users"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that `ToolUsers` is a local group on the Windows 7 PC. Local groups cannot be nested within local groups in Windows 7 (or, indeed, any prior version of Windows). It's just a limitation of the product's design.

If you can't handle just putting users in both groups you could attempt to modify local security policy to grant the same user rights to your `ToolUsers` as is already granted stock to `Remote Desktop Users` but, personally, I'd just put them in both groups.

If you have an Active Directory domain you can make `ToolUsers` a domain Global Group or Universal Group and nest it into the Windows 7 computer's local `Remote Desktop Users` group.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Creating domain group could cause delay due to the process involved. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to maintain users in 2 groups for this. Just add or remove entire Groups from "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" Policy config. I actually remove administrators from this configuration as remote admin access increases the high security risks associated with RDP.